# Update form from another form using delegate and event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, user-interface, delegates

I keep forgetting how this is done..

I want to update the UI on the main form from Form2 without creating an instance of the form.
I remember using a delegate / event and possibly passing in an instance of the first form somehow, but totally went blank.

Help me out, thanks.

Add something to listBox1 on Form1 from Form2.

Comment: i believe there was a delegate and event link from the two forms.. a delegate on form2 linked to the event in form1

Comment: Is there any way to do it without using the namespace section of code?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, delegate and event are correct key words

Implement your EventArgs class somewhere:

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private List<string> EventInfo;
    public MyEventArgs(List<string> strings)
    {
        EventInfo = strings;
    }
    public List<string> GetInfo()
    {
        return EventInfo;
    }
}
```

In Form2:

```
public class Form2
{
  public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> OnMyChange;

  //call it then you need to update:
  if(OnMyChange!= null)
  {
    MyEventArgs e = new MyEventArgs();

    List<string> content = new List<string>();
    content.Add("abc");
    e.EventInfo = content;

    OnMyChange(this, e);
  }
}
```

In Form1:

```
Form2 MyForm2 = new Form2();
MyForm2.OnMyChange += MyChanged;

static void MyChanged(object source, MyEventArgs e)
{
    //e.EventInfo will contain list
    Console.WriteLine("changed");
}
```

Comment: try adding an item to listBox1 from Form2
Just an event, not an EventHandler btw..

Comment: And why would you put stuff in the namespace?

Comment: @ploxtic 1)you can pass every object as your custom event argument, see the edit. 2)it is not stuff, it is event declaration which must be known in every class where you want to use this event

Comment: can't get it to work OnMyChange is not showing up anywhere in Form1 (listBox1.OnMyChange)

Comment: @ploxtic that was typo in my code, use MyForm2.OnMyChange just after you created the form2 instance

Comment: how do i call this thing from form 2?

Comment: @ploxtic I've extra written the comment "call it then you need to update:"

Comment: i got it, just call OnMyChange(string) in MyForm2

Comment: Is there any way to do it without putting things in the namespace section?

Comment: @ploxtic mate, I gave you fully working example. You are changing it not the appropriate way. You can't simply call OnMyChange(string) instead of OnMyChange(this, e). And no, there are only two ways, either using delegates+events or passing the form1 instance to the form2

Comment: how do you pass the form1 instance in?

Comment: @ploxtic as a constructor argument of the form 2

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update an object that you did not instantiate.

What you can do is either register some function as handler for a change event in form2. If the function is a member of the main form it can then affect the components of that form.

Passing a delegate is basically the same but would allow you to use an arbitrary function of your choosing. Most of the time this is not worth the overhead, though.

Comment: yeah the 2nd one is what i want.  Hook it up

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to get exactly what you need from the question, but it sounds like you could pass an [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) to your form for adding the items.  You could change the constructor in Form2 to ensure you always have the callback - e.g.

```
 private Action<string> addItemsToParent;

 public Form2(Action<string> addItemsToParent)
 {
    this.addItemsToParent = addItemsToParent;
 }

 public void AddItems()
 {
     addItemsToParent("item 1");
 }
```

Comment: I've fiddled with Action some, but how would you pass it correctly on a non-static form & field?  from outside threads/tasks you'd use BeginInvoke(new Action(() => listBox1.Items.Add(string)));  In this case it's not going to work.

Comment: 'from outside threads/tasks' - wouldn't the callback be coming from form2 to the main form?  (In which case the threading doesn't matter, it's still the UI thread)