# How to pass parameter between two forms with open in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I created Mdi form
now I want pass parameter 1 form to another without open form.

eg: both form open pass parameter each other.

my code working when

```
frmMain mainf = new frmMain();
mainf.rfidPort = mCobPort.SelectedItem.ToString();
mainf.tsslCom.Text = mCobPort.SelectedItem.ToString();
mainf.ShowDialog();
```

but my target appear to form A -> form B without form open.
I don't want use code below:

> mainf.ShowDialog();

Possible?

I cannot find my request in google.
If Possible how? Please guide me.
[image]

Comment: Relevant: [Update one form from another using delegate and event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15309050/2791540)

Comment: [Interaction between forms — How to change a control of a form from another form?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38768737/3110834)

Comment: @JohnWu it return Null , I want interact with 2 open form

Comment: Simply, Change the constructor of the `frmMain`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (and least elegant way) is simply to update it directly in your click handler.

In your "Save Setting" form, handle the Submit click event by updating the parent form, which in this case is frmMain.

```
void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var mainForm = this.Parent as frmMain;
    mainForm.rfidPort = this.mCobPort.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
Error Prompt

Comment: I’m guessing you did not set the form’s parent, or SelectedItem is null because no selection has been made.